# post video to facebook/twitter via sharekit

Tags: iphone, facebook, twitter, sharekit

Currently,I am developing an app in which I have to post video to Facebook/twitter via share kit.I am

sending text & images via share kit then its easily posted on Facebook/twitter but video is not post.

I am searching everywhere but can't succeeded.how can i solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: the same issue with you

Comment: @Vishal: I share video in facebook but I can't in twitter...